# BadRequestError on AppEngine remote_api stub call

Tags: python, google-app-engine, remoteapi

Trying to set up remote_api stubs in my Python 2.7 AppEngine application, to use datastore access in conjunction with my localhost debugger (test my app using real data).  Now, I've followed the tutorial on [this AppEngine Remote API article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#Using_Remote_API_in_a_Local_Client) and came up with this code (from a REST handler in our application):

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from model import MyExpandoObject

# This returns my credentials
def auth_func():
    return ("me@gmail.com", "mypassword")

# TODO This too
def get(w_self):
    # Connect remote api in identical way to example docs:
    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,'bsl-dm-hrd.appspot.com')

    # This calls the database (breakpoint here)
    t_entity = MyExpandoObject.get_by_key_name('akey')
```

Now, when I execute the code, the configuration of the stub passes.  Then, when calling the database, I get this error in my debugger:

```
    BadRequestError: app s~myapp cannot access app dev~myapp's data
```

This, I believe, is the error I need to fix.  Please do note that the s~ indicating this is an HRD application is properly reported as part of the app ID.  I have also included the

```
builtins:
    - remote_api: on
```

directive in app.yaml.

My question is, why do I get this error?  This is literally example code taken from the remote_api article.  Just in case, I have also tried remote_api connection through remote_api_shell.py, bundled with the AppEngine SDK, and was able to connect to the datastore, import models and execute database calls.  I am stumped as to why this fails.

Comment: You have got mis-matching appids'  You don't appear to be setting the appid - you have None as the first parameter to ConfigureRemoteApi  you may need to set the --partition arg of the dev_server to have the appid you want, and or supply an appid to the ConfigureRemoteApi call.

Comment: Wow! This worked.  Please, write an answer so I can accept it, Tim.  Setting the --default_partition argument is what I needed!  Thank you, so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got mis-matching appids' You don't appear to be setting the appid - you have None as the first parameter to ConfigureRemoteApi you may need to set the --partition arg of the dev_server to have the appid you want, and or supply an appid to the ConfigureRemoteApi call